# Vitest: how to exclude directory from coverage report?

Tags: unit-testing, vitest

How to exclude a directory from coverage report in vitest?

I'm looking for something like `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` option as it was in jest:

```js
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/src/foo.ts',
    '<rootDir>/src/bar.ts',
     ....
  ],
```

How could I do that in `vitest.config.ts`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inside `coverage` you need to add exclude ignore pattern.
then it will work. like this:

in vite.config.ts

```
{
...
  test: {
     ...,
     coverage: {
       provider: 'istanbul',
       exclude: ['src/config/**']
     }

  }
}
```

Don't add it outside the coverage.didn't work for me.

Comment: How can we do this via the CLI? if we need to see the coverage for a single file or folder for example?